# How to Resolve Extension Issues in Equivariant (Co)Homology Computations

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am computing equivariant homology, which is just the usual homology of the Borel construction. I have reached a few extension issues.

I have used the Gysin sequence, Leray-Serre spectral sequence, and the Universal Coefficient Theorem to go back and forth between homology and cohomology, to compute equivariant homology.

What other tools can I use that I can learn about to aid in my calculation, or to figure out the extensions?

Comment: What about Künneth formulas?

Comment: @MarcoArmenta The spaces I am computing equivariant homology of are not products, and the Borel construction is not exactly a product, so I do not think Kunneth Theorems are helpful, unless there is a use of them that I am overlooking, if so, please enlighten me.